# When listing refereed papers in a CV, should I highlight my name in authors lists?

Tags: job-search, cv

I am experimental physics grad student updating my CV / publications/talks list in preparation for applying to postdoctoral positions.

In my refereed publications list, while a few of the most recent papers have me as the first author, the majority do not. So my question is as follows: **Should I highlight my name in the lists somehow? If so, italics, boldface, or something else?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not generally see people highlighting their name in a CV in this way, and I do not think that it is necessary (though perhaps the culture in experimental physics is different).  In a CV, you are by definition an author of every listed paper, and papers where you are first author leap out pretty easily to the eye already---unless you've got *lots* of papers, in which case, why worry about it?  If you highlight your name, on the other hand, I think that it could come across as insecure, since it is not normally done.

Comment: very field specific. In my field they do. If there are 4 or less authors on all your publications, it is probably not necessary. It is only necessary if your position will not be noticed in a cursory look, such as a 10 author paper (and in some fields, yes a 10 author paper does have meaning, shockingly).

Comment: @WetLabStudent By your handle, I'm guessing that you are in biomedical sciences?  In the work that I've done in that area, I've had my share of high-number papers (the largest at the moment is 32), and I've not seen this sort of highlighting amongst my collaborators or their students...

Comment: nope not in the bio-medical sciences, wetlabs exist in all of the natural sciences. I don't doubt your personal experience, this may just be field specific in a cultural (rather than rational) way.

Comment: @WetLabStudent I'm not doubting your experience either: I am, however, wondering what your field is?

Comment: Actually my user name is meant to be somewhat ironic, I'm an mathematical biologist who does 'some' limited experiments. And as a Theoretician I do them rather poorly, hence wetlabstudent is my nickname, despite basically every component of the name being incorrect. BTW I will delete this comment eventually to avoid this answer from turning into a conversation